# In an anti-matter universe, would an anti-matter black hole emit anti-matter gamma radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, antimatter, gamma-rays

In an anti-matter universe, when an anti-matter black hole is consuming a large anti-matter star, would it emit anti-matter gamma radiation, or would gamma radiation be the same in either a matter or anti-matter universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photons are their own antiparticle, so they are the same in an universe of matter and a universe of antimatter.